# webdriver, cast "By" to string

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is it possible to cast the selenium/webdriver "By" object to sting, e.g.:

```
By locator1 = By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'" + button2press + "')]");
By locator2 = By.cssSelector("input[class='image'][checked='checked']");
```

I need something like:

```
String str1 = "//a[contains(text(),'" + button2press + "')]";
String str2 = "input[class='image'][checked='checked']";
```

If i could get the locating "method" this would be a bonus:

```
String method1 = "xpath";
String method2 = "cssSelector";
```

Comment: Locating method... `CSS` or `XPath` is enough? Or do you need all kind of locating methods?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have 2 selectors

```
By.cssSelector("input[class='here i am']");
By.xpath("//*[@class='here i am']");
```

In order to cast them to String use `toString()` method.
The output is following:

```
By.cssSelector: input[class='here i am']
By.xpath: //*[@class='here i am']
```

The above are Strings. You got the selector. Let's get locating method.
As you can see, locating method is already in our String. We just have to parse it to get locating method. We can do it in many ways. `Regex` or `split()` or `indexOf()`

Example:

```
String mySelector = "By.cssSelector: input[class='here i am']";
String locating method = mySelector.split(":")[0].trim()
```

Now, we can create methods to get desired results.

```
public String getSelector(By by) {
    return by.toString().split(":")[1];
}

public String getLocatingMethod(By by) {
    return by.toString().split(":")[0]; //returns "By.cssSelector", "By.xpath" etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
    By locator1 = By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'" + button2press + "')]");
    String str = locator1.toString();
    String pat1 = "(By.)(.*)(:)( )(.*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, with the proven and powerful [**toString()**](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method) *Java* method you can cast the selenium/webdriver **By** object to **String**. But a lot would depend on the *usecase* you are dealing with.

At this point is is worth to mention that the [*WebDriver*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) methods [`findElement()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and [`findElements()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) accepts arguments of `By` type only as follows :

- [**findElement()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

  ```
  WebElement findElement(By by)

  Parameters:
  by - The locating mechanism

  Returns:
  The first matching element on the current page

  Throws:
  NoSuchElementException - If no matching elements are found
  ```
- [**findElements()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

  ```
  java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by)

  Parameters:
  by - The locating mechanism to use

  Returns:
  A list of all WebElements, or an empty list if nothing matches
  ```

So even if you cast the selenium/webdriver **By** objects to **String** objects they won't be usable in your *@Tests*. Hence casting the **By** objects to **String** objects won't add any value.

However if you want to pass a **String** to construct a unique dynamic `xpath` which would be used to construct a **By** object, you can always write a function as follows to invoke `click()` on the specific `<a>` tag with a variable text as follows :

```
public void clickElement(string myElement)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//a[.='" + myElement + "']")).click();
}
```

Now if your *Application Under Test (AUT)* is having several links to be clicked, you can invoke the `clickElement(string myElement)` function anytime from your `main()` or `@Test` annotated Class as follows :

```
clickElement("Login");
clickElement("Logout");
```

Comment: i need the string for a more detailed debug output, not for location the elements

Comment: @roli Check out my answer. It might help you to fulfill your goal.

Comment: @roli For a _detailed debug output_ you can always set the log level to **trace** and get all the required information.

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to setup a custom debug log